# Magento SOAP API not giving data

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I'm trying to test the SOAP API in my Magento Community install.

I created a role, a user  and a PHP file containing:

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // Of course I inserted my url here
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // And my user and API key

$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
var_dump($result);

The result is a completely blank page, although I do have some categories in the shop.

Does anybody recognize this and know how to remedy it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

- Check your web server error log
- Insert the following code at the top of your script to view the PHP errors:

`error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

- What web server and OS are you using? Usually on Linux, you need to install php-soap separately to enable SOAP calls.

Comment: Hi Francis,

Thanks very much for your reply!
I solved the problem just now, by comparing a clean magento install with the one that gave the problems.

Difference:

Clean install: when setting up SOAP user, it asks for the admin password and the SOAP role works.
My Ma Racima themed install does not ask the admin password and the SOAP role does not work.

Problem seems to originate in the MA Racima Theme install package that I used for the shop.
I'm now recreating the webshop from scratch. Thusfar the SOAP role works!

Thanks again for your answer and have a splendid day!
Bye
Ward

Comment: Can i get help regard soap error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/249612/57334 @Francis Kim