# How to solve Soap_V2 - Uncaught SoapFault exception looks like we got no XML document - SoapClient->__call('login', Array)?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, products, soap-api-v2

After configuration SOAP_v2 for getting products info,

**Magento version : 1.9.2.3**

Code:

```
<?php
$proxy = new SoapClient('abc.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'bala', 'apiKey' => 'bala123'));
$result = $proxy->catalogProductInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'productId' => '9699'));
var_dump($result->result);
?>
```

And error is,

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in /home/abc/public_html/bala.php:3
Stack trace:

*#0 /home/abc/public_html/bala.php(3): SoapClient->__call('login', Array)*
*#1 {main}*
  thrown in /home/abc/public_html/bala.php on line 3*

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SAOP UI to import your wsdl and see if some errors are returned (to valid if your wsdl format is correct).

Then, if not, call function login to get your sessionId, then call catalogProductInfo.

See if you get some errors (or warnings) and try to fix them.

You can aslo add debug on your code with try/catch for exemple :

```
try 
{ 
    //your code
} 
catch (exception $e) 
{ 
    var_dump($e->getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: My source code : https://justpaste.it/57n29 Output : https://snag.gy/VsXjNv.jpg

Comment: What's in your file `abc.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl` ?

Comment: https://snag.gy/1fAnkB.jpg @Kozame

Comment: Did you check if the format of your wsdl is correct ? For instance, with https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ ?

Comment: Xml validator return error, https://snag.gy/hvEcL9.jpg. This is what magento soap url right? pls correct me.

Comment: I am new in SOAP, can you pls help to find out the solution?

Comment: When you test your xml, start with <wsdl[...] (remove the first line "This XML[...])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85696/discussion-between-zus-and-kozame).

Comment: get session ID and get response  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85696/discussion-between-zus-and-kozame

Comment: Great Support by Kozame, thank you very much.

Comment: Now values return as Object, how can i get as XML? @Kozame

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85696/discussion-between-zus-and-kozame